# What does * mean in ssh reverse forward?

Tags: ssh, forwarding

What does `*` mean in the below `ssh` command?

```
ssh -R *:1993:localhost:22 root@23.105.207.175
```

The `*` means 23.105.207.175?
And are there different meanings for the below three expressions?

expression1:

```
ssh -R *:1993:localhost:22 root@23.105.207.175
```

expression2:

```
ssh -R 23.105.207.175:1993:localhost:22 root@23.105.207.175
```

expression3:

```
ssh -R 1993:localhost:22 root@23.105.207.175
```

Comment: Related - [Which server do I login via ssh's local port forward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589720/100397)

Comment: Hello it_is_a_literature. Have you looked at the documentation for `ssh` at all? Try `man ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

The basic syntax for reverse tunneling with `ssh` is:

`ssh -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport [user@]hostname`

> By default, the listening socket on the server will be bound to the
>   loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a
>   `bind_address`. An empty `bind_address`, or the address `*`, indicates
>   that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.

From your question:

**Expression1** => All interfaces are bounded.

**Expression2** => The interface with IP address `23.105.207.175` is bounded.

**Expression3** => The `loopback` interface is bounded.

`man` is your friend => https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: "_`man` is your friend_" - and it should ready be installed without needing to be online, i.e. `man ssh`

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `:8888:localhost:8888` and `8888:localhost:8888`; in the former the bind address has been specified as _empty_ (so listen everywhere) but in the latter it's been omitted (so listen only locally). This subtlety can be very confusing.

Comment: Also, the remote sshd server has to allow the change. (see `man sshd_config`'s `GatewayPorts` option, not `man ssh_config`'s `GatewayPorts` option).